# AssertionError: 400 != 201 when running APITestCase after TestCase

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here is the problem:
I have 2 seperate tests, one is based on Django's TestCase and another one inherits from APITestCase (Django Rest Framework). When running separately no errors occur, but when I run APITestCase after TestCase self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED) doesn't work anymore.

Here is a part of code:

```
class CalendarTests(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(
            email='test@test.com', password='secret', username='tester')
        self.calendar = Calendar(owner=self.user, caltype='p', name='Test Calendar')
        self.calendar.save();

    def test_api_create_bla(self):
        self.client.login(username='test@test.com', password='secret')
        url = reverse('calendar-api')
        data_initial = {'text': 'testing hurray', 'cal_date':'2015-03-15', 'calendar':1}
        data_expected = {'cal_date': '2015-03-15',
                         'text': u'testing hurray',
                         'otype': 'd', 
                         'owner': u'tester', 
                         'calendar': 1,
                         'id': 1}

        response = self.client.post(url, data_initial, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, data_expected)
        self.client.logout()
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are getting a 400 response (bad request). You should print out `request.data` for further diagnosis.

Comment: post the corresponding view.

Comment: @KlausD. there is no request object (or is there?), but printing the response showed me it the calendar id was invalid. Finally, the problem was in the MySQL IntegrityError and ForeignKeys as I am using InnoDB. The solution I found was to use MyISAM when running tests.

Comment: Thanks, @KlausD, you are right, response object contains request. Just read the docs carefully )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, guys, thanks, it's solved for me. 
By printing response object I figured out that calendar_id was wrong. Because I use MySQL with InnoDB (maybe have to switch to PostreSQL), the IntegrityError "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" caused strange behaviour in the second test. The solution that helped me is to switch in settings.py from InnoDB engine to MyISAM this way:

```
db_options = "INNODB"
import sys
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    db_options = "MYISAM"

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'callist',     
       'USER': 'test',
       'PASSWORD': 'test',
       'HOST': 'localhost',               
       'PORT': '80',                      
       'OPTIONS': {'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=' + db_options},
    }
}
```

Will think of switching to PostreSQL.
Thanks for those who tried to help.